# can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str? How to get rid of tuple?

Tags: python

```
while True:
        time.sleep(SLEEP_BETWEEN_ACTIONS)
        input_1 = input("\n" + player1_name + ": " + random.choice(player_turn_text) + " Hit the enter to roll dice: ")
        print("\nRolling dice...")
        dice_value = get_dice_value()
        time.sleep(SLEEP_BETWEEN_ACTIONS)
        print(player1_name + " moving....")
        player1_current_position = snake_ladder(player1_name, player1_current_position, dice_value)

        check_win(player1_name, player1_current_position)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

My error log says

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

```
input_1 = input("\n" + player1_name + ": " + random.choice(player_turn_text) + " Hit the enter to roll dice: ")
```

Comment: player1_name or result of random.choice is tuple. We cannot help without knowing what these values are.

Comment: Either `player1_name` is a tuple or `random.choice` is returning a tuple.

Comment: Please provide the whole traceback. And reproducible code. What is `player1_name`? Apart from that error is pretty explicit, something you think is a string is actually a tuple

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the signatures of the function you use, and that are not present in the attached code. But it seems, one of the elements here:

```
+ player1_name + ": " + random.choice(player_turn_text) +
```

Returns tuple.

The simplest solution to that, would be to call it like str(player1_name) - and the same with the other one.